# Javascript WebBluetooth Printer Works On Desktop / Laptop Browsers But Not Working On Smartphone Browsers

Tags: javascript, php

I am developing a website that able to print receipt. However, I can connect to my Bluetooth Thermal Printer and print a proper receipt using Chrome on MacBook.

[image: 1]

But when i use any android device Chrome browser, the printing is either keep on stuck, or the results were printed as below.
[image: 2]
Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can only guess there. But I'd say bytes sent by your web bluetooth app varies enough so that the device understands it differently.

Can you try sending less bytes at once and see how it reacts?
Can you share your source code as well?

You may want to look into your android device logs as well. See full instructions at [https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs#:~:text=following%20these%C2%A0instructions.-,Android,-ADB%20logs](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs#:%7E:text=following%20these%C2%A0instructions.-,Android,-ADB%20logs)

```
adb logcat -v time | grep -E " |[Bb]luetooth|cr.Bluetooth|BtGatt|BluetoothGatt|bt_btif_config"
```

Comment: Thanks there, i already solve it. Seperating the whole string text and send it one by one may solve this. Like what u mention above.

Comment: @Batgolira  What is the printer model you used with webbluetooth? I have a web application and need to print a receipt for a retail operation. Any bluetooth printer will do with webbluetooth?